# StoreLocator using google Javascript API

Tags: javascript, php, html

my code doesn't seem to give html "id=latitude and longitude" values from javascript geolocation functions. using document.getElementByID("Id").value = "value"; it isnt the right way? please check the code below. maybe i am missing something. after my hidden values are given everything must be posted to storelocator.php

```
<body>


<form method="GET" action="storelocator.php" > 

    <input onclick="getLocation()" type="submit"  value="Try">
    <input id="latitudeId" name="lat" type="hidden" >
    <input id="longitudeId" name="lng" type="hidden" >

    <div class="dropdown">   
     <select name="radius">
      <option value="1000">1000</option>
      <option value="500" selected="selected" >500</option>
      <option value="300">300</option>
      <option value="100">100</option>
    </select>
    </div>      

</form>

<p id="show"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
var x = document.getElementById("show");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }

    function showPosition(position) {
      var lat = position.coords.latitude;
      var lng = position.coords.longitude;

      document.getElementByID("latitudeId").value = lat;
      document.getElementByID("longitudeId").value = lng;
     }
 }    

</script>


</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is working. I just display the result inside the console.
First error, you made somethign weird with your function `showPosition` being created inside your getLocation and I think missing a `}`

About your getElementById, be carefull, it's `getElementById` and not `getElementByID` with a capital D.

```js
var x = document.getElementById("show");
var form = document.querySelector('form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    getLocation();
});

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
      var lat = position.coords.latitude;
      var lng = position.coords.longitude;

      document.getElementById("latitudeId").value = lat;
      document.getElementById("longitudeId").value = lng;

      form.submit();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="GET" action="storelocator.php" > 
    
        <input type="submit"  value="Try">
        <input id="latitudeId" name="lat" type="hidden" >
        <input id="longitudeId" name="lng" type="hidden" >
    
        <div class="dropdown">   
         <select name="radius">
          <option value="1000">1000</option>
          <option value="500" selected="selected" >500</option>
          <option value="300">300</option>
          <option value="100">100</option>
        </select>
        </div>      
    
    </form>
    
    <p id="show"></p>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks,The thing is i would like to give html hidden values the location values. The problem is when it redirect to storelocator.php , the url shows that some values are missing it shows this: http://localhost/mywebsite/storelocator.php?lat=&lng=&radius=500 , so i assume this means lat and lng did not get values only radius.

Comment: just updated the code. It wasn't working because when your form was redirecting you immediatly on the new page, without waiting for the geolocation. 

Now the form wait to have the geolocation, then redirect. I tested it, and it's working with chrome and firefox

Comment: Okay, Thanks. I see you made some changes ill try that out shortly.

Comment: I see where i went wrong, anyway Thanks it worked. yay!